# CodeIgniter not seeing parameters from valum's ajax file uploader

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, post, get

I'm using the Valums AJAX file uploader with CodeIgniter 2.1.0. When I try to pass parameters to my ajax controller, nothing seems to get passed.

```
function initializeAttachmentUploader(obj) {
    element = document.getElementById(obj);

    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        multiple: true,
        element: element,
        action: '<?php echo site_url('ajax/attachment_upload'); ?>/' + $('#token').val(),
        debug: true,
        params: { test: 'dsfasdfasdfasdf' },
    });
}
```

And in the ajax attachment_upload function

```
$param = $this->input->get('test');
```

Always comes up as NULL. I'm using CodeIgniter, allow_get_array is TRUE. I have also tried:

```
$param = $this->input->post('test');
```

No errors, other than it's just NULL. What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to enable query string for that to work.

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

From the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):

> **Please note:** If you are using query strings you will have to build
>   your own URLs, rather than utilizing the URL helpers (and other
>   helpers that generate URLs, like some of the form helpers) as these
>   are designed to work with segment based URLs.